# JSP forms with Spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I create the following JSP.This jsp creates two buttons.

```
<form:form method="POST"  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/link">    
     <div class="button-container" style="float:left;clear:right">
        <table>

            <tr>
               <td>
                  <input id="post" type="image" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/<spring:theme code="image"/>votup.png" 
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="hidden">    
                <td class="hidden">           
                  <input type="text" name="mark" value="up"/> 
                </td>
            </tr>

     <tr>
                <td>
                   <input id="post" type="image" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/<spring:theme code="image"/>votdown.png" 
                </td>
             </tr>

             <tr class="hidden">
                <td class="hidden">
                    <input type="text" name="mark" value="down"/>
                </td>
             </tr>
```

In the controller class

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/link", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String sendMark(@RequestParam("mark") final String marking){


 }
```

I notice that the value of the String marking= up,down.This happens no matter which of the 2 buttons i click. Instead of this i want to be only up or down according to the button that the user will click.(If click at the first button should be up, if click at the second button should be down). I understood that the reason i take this result is because i named both of the hidden values as mark, but i don't know how to make the seperation with another way. Actually is the first time i'm doing something with JSP.Could i use some tag libraries for this problem?Any comments or answers are much appreciated! 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise you to put only one hidden field and change its value with javascript before processing the POST command.

Comment: could you please provide some code.I'm newbie in the web technologies and i don't know javascript.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to create two separate forms for the two buttons and both form will contain the hidden field. Now you will get only one value.

But if you create two separate forms with different actions then you won't need the hidden field.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand, you will submit the form eithef for vote up or down. And you want 2 buttons for each action in the same form, but don't know how to make the difference. I would do something like this:

On form, put the action according to your request mapping (seems already done).
Then, both buttons would be made to submit the form. First of all, both your buttons have the same id, and the id has to be unique for each element. So, give your arrows and form id's like:

```
<input id="postup" type="image" 
<input id="postdown" type="image"
<form id="myform"
```

Then, pun an onclick action on it like:
     
And create 2 JS functions:

```
function postUp () {
   $('#mark').val("up");
   $('#myform').submit();
}
function postDown () {
   $('#mark').val("down");
   $('#myform').submit();
}
```

Your controller will look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/link", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendMark(Model model, HttpServletRequest request){

String mark = request.getParameter("mark");
return "yourjsp"
}
```

And you will have your value.
Hope it helps !
Regards !